# Google sheets app scripts - Slow Performance. Need suggestions for speed up

Tags: javascript, performance, google-apps-script, google-sheets

I use the apps script to create dynamic dependent dropdowns for each row across several sheets. (unfortunately, this the only way to create dynamic dropdowns for ALL rows, formula method only works for ONE row). The dynamic dependent dropdown for a particular column is dependent on one or more previous columns.

For example, in sheet "Assembly Info", user selects value for column A from a pre-defined dropdown. Based on the value selected, the dropdowns for columns B,C,D,E,F are generated sequentially i.e. dropdown for Column C after value in B is selected and dropdown for F is generated for values in columns A,C,D,E etc. Basically, the apps script is generating the dropdown (say for Column F) by filtering data from another page based on values entered in previous (Columns A,C,D,E). There are currently 6 such sheets which use the same logic and about 3000 rows of data per sheet and increasing.

[image]

Following is the code for generating dynamic dropdowns:

```
function dynamicDropdown(){
  
  // Get active sheet 
  var ss = SpreadsheetApp.getActiveSpreadsheet().getActiveSheet();
    
  // Log active sheet name for testing
  // Logger.log(sheetName);
     
  var listss = SpreadsheetApp.getActiveSpreadsheet().getSheetByName("Setup");
  var listPSI = SpreadsheetApp.getActiveSpreadsheet().getSheetByName("Plating Sent Info");
  var listPRI = SpreadsheetApp.getActiveSpreadsheet().getSheetByName("Plating Recd Info"); 
  var listIB = SpreadsheetApp.getActiveSpreadsheet().getSheetByName("Incoming Blanks"); 
    
  // Get active cell in active sheet
  var activeCell = ss.getActiveCell()

  // Following example code block shows dynamic dropdown for sheet "Assembly Info" Column F
  // There are about **25** such IF code blocks within dynamicDropdown()

  // Code Block - 1 (Create dynamic dropdown for Column F (6) in "Assembly Info" Sheet
  if(activeCell.getColumn() == 5 && activeCell.getRow() > 1 && ss.getName() == "Assembly Info"){
    // Dynamic dropdowns for assembly info sku list

    activeCell.offset(0,1).clearContent().clearDataValidations();
        
    if(activeCell.isBlank() == false){

      if(activeCell.offset(0,-4).getValue() == "Plated"){

        var plvDC = activeCell.offset(0,-1).getValue();
        var plVendor = activeCell.offset(0,-2).getValue();
        var prodType = activeCell.getValue();
            
        var PRI_VendorSKU_Data = listPRI.getRange(2,2,listPRI.getLastRow()-1,6).getValues();
        //Logger.log(PRI_VendorDC_Data);

        // compute SKU types sent using FILTER
        var plvSKUList = PRI_VendorSKU_Data.filter(function(item){
        return item[1] === plVendor && item[2] === plvDC && item[4] === prodType;  
        })

        //Logger.log(plvSKUList);

        var distinct = (value,index,self) => {
          return self.indexOf(value) === index;
        }
      
        var plvSKUValidationList = plvSKUList.map(x => x[5]).sort();
        //Logger.log(plvSKUValidationList);

      var plvSKUValidationRule = SpreadsheetApp.newDataValidation().requireValueInList(plvSKUValidationList).setAllowInvalid(false).build();      
      
        // Apply validation rule to adjacent cell using offset
        activeCell.offset(0,1).setDataValidation(plvSKUValidationRule);   

      }

      else if(activeCell.offset(0,-4).getValue() == "SS"){

        var ssRecdDate = activeCell.offset(0,-3).getValue();
        var prodType = activeCell.getValue();
            
        var IB_VendorSKU_Data = listIB.getRange(2,1,listIB.getLastRow()-1,4).getValues();
        //Logger.log(PRI_VendorDC_Data);

        // compute SKU types sent using FILTER
        var ssSKUList = IB_VendorSKU_Data.filter(function(item){
        return item[0] <= ssRecdDate && item[1] === prodType && item[2] === "Assembly - SS Condition";  
        })

        var distinct = (value,index,self) => {
          return self.indexOf(value) === index;
        }
      
        var ssSKUValidationList = ssSKUList.map(x => x[3]).filter(distinct).sort();
        //Logger.log(ssSKUValidationList);

      var ssSKUValidationRule = SpreadsheetApp.newDataValidation().requireValueInList(ssSKUValidationList).setAllowInvalid(false).build();      
      
        // Apply validation rule to adjacent cell using offset
        activeCell.offset(0,1).setDataValidation(ssSKUValidationRule);   
        
      }
       
            
    }        

  }

  // Code block - 2 (create dynamic dropdown for column B in Sheet "X"
  if(activeCell.getColumn() == 1 && activeCell.getRow() > 1 && ss.getName() == "X"){
  ...
  }

  .
  .
  .

  // Code block - 25 (create dynamic dropdown for Column D in Sheet "Y"
  if(activeCell.getColumn() == 3 && activeCell.getRow() > 1 && ss.getName() == "Y"){
  ...
  }
  
}

function onEdit(){
  // Inbuilt trigger that runs when particular cell is edited 
  // Objectives: Dependent dropdown lists for drawing ref   
  
  // Function call
  dynamicDropdown();  
  
}
```

I checked the "Executions" page in the app script editor to check average time for execution:
[image]

What are some suggestions to improve the speed? At some times, it takes about 6-8 seconds for a dropdown to appear in adjacent column. Currently, the dynamicDropdown() function has about 25 IF code blocks and I am guessing this is cause for slow performance. For any change in particular column X in sheet Y in the workbook, code execution has to go through all code blocks sequentially until a IF code block with matching condition is found: `if(activeCell.getColumn() == X && activeCell.getRow() > 1 && ss.getName() == "Y")`

What are some suggestions to optimize this code block to improve execution speed?

Comment: Although I'm not sure whether this is the direct solution of your issue, when you run the script by OnEdit trigger, as a simple method for reducing the process cost, how about using the event object? When the event object is used, the process cost can be reduced a little. [Ref](https://gist.github.com/tanaikech/4892c97df7ac0504ffd715c2dd6cd546) As another direction, for example, how about using Sheets API? When Sheets API is used, the process cost can be reduced. But in this case, the installable trigger is required to be used. If those were not the direction you expect, I apologize.

Comment: @Tanaike I looked into the process cost results in your reference link on how event objects can reduce execution time. I am not sure how i can incorporate event objects into existing code. Can you provide an example?

Comment: Thank you for replying. For example, you can see about the event object at this official document. https://developers.google.com/apps-script/guides/triggers/events If this was not useful, I apologize. By the way, how do you run your script? If you have not run the script by the OnEdit trigger, the event object cannot be used. I'm worried about this.

Comment: Besides, you should try to replace all the `getValue`s with one `getValues`. See [Best Practices](https://developers.google.com/apps-script/guides/support/best-practices)

Comment: @Tanaike thank you for reply. I currently use the built-in `onEdit` trigger as you can see from my code sample above. Can I pass the event object `e` to my `dynamicDropdown` function? I guess event object `e` contains information on which cell / range / sheet was modified. May be I can use this information in deciding which IF block to execute? I am not sure if this is correct

Comment: @idfurw I am using getValue based on when a particular IF code is executed. I wouldn't know beforehand which cell in the google sheet is going to change (across multiple sheets). Also, since the dropdowns are dynamic and dependent on previous column(s), getting values using `getValues` may not have the latest value. How would you do this? Can you provide an example?